Is there a designated way to delete a pointer and set it to nullptr in C++?
In my c++ code, I often have blocks like this:
if (m_pointer) {
   delete m_pointer;
   m_pointer = nullptr;
}

I just wonder, whether there is a better, designated, way to do it than repeating this block all over my code. Smart pointers are not an option here, since it's all about QObjects, which don't really support them afaik.

In the old days, before smart pointers, I used to have a macro for that. I guess you can also write a function template.

Note, that if you deal with QObject you don't need to delete each object explicitly. Qt has so called object trees that manages deletion of QObject hierarchies.

Yes, this is std::unique_ptr,

e.g. in destructors of classes ... m_pointer = nullptr; There is no sense of doing that in a destructor, at the end of the object live.

And note that the if is not required at all

And what do you think are the problems of using QObject with smart pointer?

According to this site: In all cases, if ptr is a null pointer, the standard library deallocation functions do nothing. So if checking is redundant

@3CxEZiVlQ I removed the reference to destructors, which was a bit misleading. I see, that setting to nullptr does nothing there.

This may be interesting reading. It seems that QObject is already somewhat 'smart'.

Why do you think you cannot use standard library smart pointers? Qt has no problem with them, you can easily have e.g. std::unique_ptr<Ui::MyWidget> _ui; _ui->setupUi(this); . Take a look at my old answer where I explained how QObjects manage the lifetime of their children.

Ensure the pointer ceases to exist immediately after the delete (or, at the least, is never used while it exists) and the problem goes away - no need to set the pointer to null.   Once way to achieve that is to manage the pointer in a dedicated class, where new expressions happen in constructors and delete expressions in the destructor.    Member functions (called after constructor completes and before destructor commences) also don't need to set the pointer to null unless they deallocate using delete and don't reallocate.

Since deleting a nullptr is safe, you don't need to check, and to set it to nullptr you can just "exchange" it.
#include<utility>
...
    delete std::exchange(m_pointer, nullptr);

https://godbolt.org/z/eKqh7oWPW
But if you are looking for this kind of automaticity, consider using std::unique_ptr instead.
Here is GCC producing identical machine code for the two types of constructs: https://godbolt.org/z/aP5hsT7fv

NB: This is not as interesting or useful as it looks, why? because any non-trivial use of null state for a pointer generally also controls other parts of the logic of the program or the class for which this pointer is a member.
In these cases you need to do the if(m_pointer) conditional anyway to control that.
And in the cases where this is trivial, you can already use std::unique_ptr, which precisely tracks its internal state through a null pointer.
Finally, putting this kind of code in destructors is controversial at best, because there is no need to set a member variable that is about to expire.

this looks good, can someone confirm that it does the same as my code block?

Multiple upvotes confirm it ;-)  What is your doubt ?

@Libavi, is my reputation not enough? :) . Here is the "proof" I have: under any non-trivial optimization level, both construct give the same machine code. https://godbolt.org/z/aP5hsT7fv

If you are working with QObjects you could use QPointer which is automatically cleared inside the QObject destructor, you just need to delete m_pointer.get(); and all connected QPointers will be turned null.
This is Qt's way of having weak smart pointers, other GUI libraries likely have one too, ie: wxWeakRef and Gobject.WeakRef (C++ version is in glibmm).
It is usually a good idea to search your framework documentation for weak references or pointers.
Note: As a special exception a QObject can store std::unique_ptr to its children because the unique_ptr will be destroyed before the parent, and destroying an object unparents it, and you can just set the unique_ptr to nullptr to destroy the object, but if you are not the parent or you are in doubt then use QPointer instead. (For example if you are going to use deleteLater then you must use QPointer)

I am not familiar with Qt and cannot confirm if QObject can be used with smart pointers.  If it can - this is the right path.
If you must manage a raw pointer manually, you can use this function template:
template <typename T>
void safe_delete(T*& p)
{
    delete p; 
    p = nullptr;
}

And the usage:
safe_delete(m_pointer);

Note that there's no point checking if p is nullptr assuming the default operator delete is used (because it is guaranteed to do nothing with a null pointer).
If you want to avoid a template for some reason (which I cannot foresee), you can use a macro:
#define SAFE_DELETE(p)  { delete p; p=nullptr; } while (0)

And the usage:
SAFE_DELETE(m_pointer);

Note: usually macros are not recommended, but in this specific case I believe it is somewhat acceptable (but the template version is preferable).

I should probably clarify my previous comment: Technically the user is allowed to supply a operator delete that does perform some action when passed a null pointer value. And then it is unspecified whether delete will actually call it on a null pointer value. So there may potentially be a difference in having the null pointer check, but I hope that isn't relevant in practice.

@user17732522 Sure. I added that delete a nul pointer does nothing when using the default operator.

If you just stop using raw pointers and switch to using shared_ptr or unique_ptr, then you won't have to explicitly delete the pointer. You can just let it go out of scope or explicitly invoke reset on it to release the reference.

@selbie I agree, wrote it in the first sentence of my answer. But the OP mentioned they cannot use smart pointers.

fyi... there's no need to explicitly check for null before invoking delete. It's perfectly safe to say, "delete p" even if p is NULL.

@selbie I know and also wrote it above (above the 2nd version of macro, and also in the template). See also the first comment above about that being guaranteed only with the default operator.

60% of this answer is taken up by bad code. The rest is code that’s at least superficially fine, though it arguably solves the wrong problem (nulling a pointer after freeing is at best a controversial practice, and at worst hides code design).

@KonradRudolph I merely attempted to answer the OP's explicit question. And regarding macros - I guess it is a matter of opinion. I rarely find them useful but here they are acceptable IMHO. In any case there's also the templated version.

This is a terrible macro - consider the while (0) idiom to improve it.  I disagree that a macro is acceptable here, particularly as there's no reason it couldn't be a function instead: template<typename T> void delete_and_reset(T*&p){ delete p; p=nullptr; }

@TobySpeight I posted that exact function template after the marcos. In any case I editted to show the template first as it is the better approach.

@wohlstad I absolutely agree that macros can be an acceptable (codegen) tool. But in a case where a trivial function template solves the issue just as well, the added downsides of macros basically disqualify them.

@KonradRudolph I agree, and editted the answer to emphasise the template solution. I kept the macro just in case the OP woud like to avoid it for some reason I cannot foresee.

@KonradRudolph Maybe I'm just being sentimental here. In the old days before smart pointers were standard etc, I remember it was quite common to use a macro for such a case (although I cannot remember why anybody prefered it over a template - maybe a remnant from C). But anyway I agree that it's generally not good practice.


Smart pointers are not an option here, since it's all about QObjects, which don't really support them afaik.

You are mistaken. Qt interacts with smart pointers fine. It doesn't use them in its examples, because they all relate to objects with parent-child relationships, which Qt also manages within the class QObject. It's perfectly fine to use smart pointers. ~QObject() will remove this from the parents list of children, if there is a parent.
Most of the time, the reason you want to delete a pointer is that the lifetime of the pointer is about to end. You don't need to null it, because nothing can read the value. In the rare occasions that the pointer is continuing to exist, it would be better to use a smart pointer, and reset() it.
